# python swagger client set host and port

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-codegen

How should you specify host and port in the python client library auto-generated by `swagger-codegen`?

The only documentation that I found is [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/python).

Comment: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg that's during generation time, but I want to specify this info at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target host gets hard-coded in the client code, e.g.:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/client/petstore/python/petstore_api/configuration.py#L50

```python
# configuration.py

...

def __init__(self):
  """Constructor"""
  # Default Base url
  self.host = "http://petstore.swagger.io:80/v2"
```

Comment: Ok, but this is not way to override it, maybe for debug purposes, but you must configure it in app initialization dynamically

Answer (score 10):

Bit of an old one but since this is where I landed first when searching, I'll provide my solution:

```
configuration = swagger_client.Configuration()
configuration.host = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
api_client = swagger_client.ApiClient(configuration=configuration)
api_instance = swagger_client.DefaultApi(api_client=api_client)
```

But since the configuration gets hard coded, for our project I'll likely end up having a different client for different environments (staging, prod etc).

Comment: If you don't specify a host/port in the openAPI spec, and you want to avoid duplicating the default base URL, you might prepend the host and port to the default base URL, like this: `config.host = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' + config.host`